# How configure the certificate when the octt (OCPP Compliancy Testing Tool) as the central_system use costume certificate?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, ocpp

My project need to implement the ocpp tls , so i write the server and client using nodejs. And i use the costume certificate , i add the certificate to the server and the client , they can connect each other.

But when i use the octt to connect my server faile. And octt log the General SSLEngine problem.So could somebody tell how to configure the octt's certificate when it as the central_system to connect my server.Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLzKl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to share my configuration.
You can find certificate file which OCA supported "./root/stores/" directory.
You can give your own BasicAuthPassword.
I hope this helps you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM2bV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFdiV.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do you know about custom certificate settings? We need to change the 'security.properties'  file when using a custom certificate. I have ca and cs certificates but OCTT can't connect to my server. but when I  use the OCA certificate OCTT can connect to my server. do you know about this setting and how to config 'security.properties'?

Comment: Hi, your answer may address the problem; however, here in SO is discouraged to put code/snippets in imgs. That's why:  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)